# autoCompleteTextView shows results only after deleting a letter

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I created a layout that has an `autoCompleteTextView` in it that should show some names of books.

I noticed that it show no results in some cases unless I delete one letter and then it shows the correct results.

For example, I have an array string of books that has the word Potter in them.

When I type Potter, it shows no results:

[image]

However, if I then delete one letter it suddenly shows:

[image]

The code im using to populate the list is:

```
atv_Search.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


        if (s.length() > 0) {

            SOME CODE TO GET NAMES

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>( autoBookNames );
        autoBookNames.clear();
        autoBookNames.addAll( set );
        
        // UNTIL THIS POINT IT ALL WORKS GOOD AND I SEE THAT authBookNames IS NOT EMPTY, YET NOT SHOWING UNTIL DELETE

        listAutoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_auto_search, autoBookNames );
        atv_Search.setThreshold( 1 );
        atv_Search.setAdapter( listAutoAdapter );

    }
} );
```

As I wrote in the code when I debugged it, I did get all the results even before the deletion but it didn't show it for some reason.

Any reason for this? I mean most users won't think to delete a letter to show the results.

Thank you

Comment: ben following 3 solutions doesnt worked for you ???

Comment: Work and stuff you know...let me get back to my computer first to check!

Answer (score 1):

try==>

```
listAutoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_auto_search, autoBookNames );
    atv_Search.setAdapter( listAutoAdapter );

 atv_Search.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

 listAutoAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);  

}


@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


    

}
} );
```

let me know if this works

Comment: I initialize listAutoAdapter for the first time in afterTextChanged so when I try your solution I get Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference however when I used it in afterTextChanged it did the work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you think that your compare strings' index in **"SOME CODE TO GET NAMES"** is wrong (such as last index is smaller than the correct one 1 character)

Comment: Nope, tested it all. The problem is somewhere in the dropdown because the list I pass is correct for sure

Answer (score 0):

**Move**

```
  listAutoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_auto_search, autoBookNames );
        atv_Search.setThreshold( 1 );
        atv_Search.setAdapter( listAutoAdapter );
```

into onTextchanged and try once, Ben!